# De onde vem a expressão "mandar bem"?

Tags: expressões, origem-histórica

No Brasil, quando alguém faz algo com excelência é usada a expressão:

> "Você manda bem no violão!"
> "Ela mandou bem hoje."
> ou até... "Você manda muito!"

De onde veio essa expressão?

Answer (score 1):

Minha teoria não possui embasamento cientifico, mas é a seguinte:

Uma pessoa que "manda" normalmente é autoridade em determinado assunto, exemplos:

- Quem manda na sala de aula é o professor, que tem mais conhecimento
- Quem manda em uma determinada área é o chefe daquela área que possui mais conhecimento.

Colocando no seu exemplo, podemos notar a autoridade no assunto:

- Você manda bem no violão

Logo, dizer que alguém manda muito poderia significar que ela possui muito conhecimento sobre aquilo, ou em casos esporádicos, que ela mostrou destreza naquela ocasião.